# NullReferenceException Commerce Server Web Service

Tags: c#, microsoft-commerce-server, commerceserver2007

My code:

```
        ws.CategoryConfiguration cc = new ws.CategoryConfiguration();
        cc.LoadChildProducts = true;
        cc.ChildProducts.SearchOptions.PropertiesToReturn = new string[] { "BasePrice" };
```

when I run this, I get a `NullReferenceException` on the `ChildProducts` line. I know that `string[]` is an object because it's right there, so it must be `PropertiesToReturn`. Anyone know what the issue is? `LoadChildProducts` works without any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to new up the `SearchOptions` object, like this:

```
CatalogSearchOptions searchOptions = new CatalogSearchOptions();
```

Then you can add the `PropertiesToReturn`, like this:

```
searchOptions.PropertiesToReturn = "BasePrice";
```

Finally, you can assign the `searchOptions` to the `CategoryConfiguration.ChildProducts.SearchOptions` property, like this:

```
cc.ChildProducts.SearchOptions = searchOptions;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is either the `ChildProducts` or the `SearchOptions` inside the ChildProducts. 
Make sure that they get initialized in the constructor of a `CategoryConfiguration`